# how to find '\' in a string in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a function strip white-spaces from the left hand side a string.

```
def main():
    str_strip = input('enter a string of which whitespace are stripped: ')
    cs-strip(str_strip)

def cs-strip(str_strip):
    i = 0
    temp = list(str_strip)
    if  temp[0] == ' ':
        temp.remove(temp[0])
    elif temp[0] == '\' :
        if temp[1] == 'n' or temp[1] == 't':
            temp.remove(temp[0])
            temp.remove(temp[0])
    new = ''.join(map(str,temp))
    print(new)

main()
```

But I cant quote compare '\' with other strings, I have tried '''\''', it still doesn't work.
How can I compare string when string is or includes '\'?

Comment: Hint: Look at the syntax highlighting on your question.

Comment: you need to escape `\ ` character with `\ `, withich would be `temp[0] == '\\'`

Comment: The syntax says "missing a closing quote[']",which is not helpful

Comment: there's a much shorter way to remove whitespace or backslash from the left side

Comment: thanks! Our homework was to rewrite all the built-in functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `'\\'` or `r'\'` to compare with backslash like below.

```
temp[0] == '\\'
temp[0] == r'\'
```

Comment: Try this in an interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to escape it with other `\` char, so your `elif` should be like this:

```
elif temp[0] == '\\' :
```